# Custom loss function which depends on another neural network in keras

Tags: python, keras

I have a "How can I do that" question with keras :

Assuming that I have a first neural network, say NNa which has 4 inputs (x,y,z,t) which **is already trained**.
If I have a second neural network, say NNb, and that its loss function depends on the first neural network.

The custom loss function of NNb `customLossNNb` calls the prediction of NNa with a fixed grid (x,y,z) and just modify the last variable t.

Here in pseudo-python-code what I would like to do to traine the second NN : NNb:

```
grid=np.mgrid[0:10:1,0:10:1,0:10:1].reshape(3,-1).T

Y[:,0]=time
Y[:,1]=something

def customLossNNb(NNa,grid):
     def diff(y_true,y_pred): 
         for ii in range(y_true.shape[0]):
               currentInput=concatenation of grid and y_true[ii,0]
               toto[ii,:]=NNa.predict(currentInput)
               #some stuff with toto
         return #...
     return diff
```

Then

```
NNb.compile(loss=customLossNNb(NNa,K.variable(grid)),optimizer='Adam')
NNb.fit(input,Y)
```

In fact the line that cause me troubles is `currentInput=concatenation of grid and y_true[ii,0]`

I tried to send to customLossNNb the grid as a tensor with `K.variable(grid)`. But I can't defined a new tensor inside the loss function, something like `CurrentY` which has a shape `(grid.shape[0],1)` fill with `y[ii,0]`(*i.e.* the current t) and then concatenate `grid` and `currentY` to build `currentInput`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: As i've pointed out in my answer, you cannot use model.predict(x) in your loss function, since it cannot be part of the graph. Use instead model(x), but then you'll need to freeze the weights properly. Also tensor.shape attribute is not the part of the graph. To be part of the graph, this need to return tensor object. You can use  keras.backend.shape(tensor). For loop will also not be part of the graph. Generally, I think you need to clarify the concept of a graph object for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can include your custom loss function into the graph using functional API of keras. The model in this case can be used as a function, something like this:

```
for l in NNa.layers: 
    l.trainable=False
x=Input(size)
y=NNb(x)
z=NNa(y)
```

Predict method will not work, since loss function should be part of the graph, and predict method returns np.array

Comment: Warning: although correct, you will need to change your targets for this to work by predicting them with `NNa`: `newTargets = NNa.predict(oldTargets)`.

Comment: i assumed that the there are targets for NNa from the very beginning and no targets for NNb, otherwise it's easier to use them directly... Even though i can imagine cases where this still can be reasonable

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your answer, but it seems that I wasn't very clear about my problem, I added more details in the original post

Answer (score 0):

First, make `NNa` untrainable. Notice that you should do this recursively if your model has inner models.

```
def makeUntrainable(layer):
    layer.trainable = False

    if hasattr(layer, 'layers'):
        for l in layer.layers:
            makeUntrainable(l)

makeUntrainable(NNa)
```

Then you have two options:

- Attach NNa to the end of your model (notice that both `y_true` and `y_pred` will be changed)

  - Then change your targets (predict with NNa) for correct results since your model is now expecting the output of NNa, not NNb.
- Create a custom loss function that uses `NNa` inside it, without changing your targets

### Option 1 - Attaching models

```
inputs = NNb.inputs   
outputs = NNa(NNb.outputs) #make sure NNb is outputing 4 tensors to match NNa inputs   
fullModel = Model(inputs,outputs)

#changing the targets:
newY_train = NNa.predict(oldY_train)
```

### Option 2 - Creating a custom loss

> Warning: please test whether NNa's weights are really frozen while training this configuration

```
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy

def customLoss(true,pred):
    true = NNa(true)
    pred = NNa(pred)

    #use some of the usual losses or create your own
    binary_crossentropy(true,pred)

NNb.compile(optimizer=anything, loss = customLoss)
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your answer, but it seems that I wasn't very clear about my problem, I added more details in the original post